# Specific Keyboard for my app

Tags: android, keyboard

I am working on app having input of different language. Is it possible to create separate language keyboard and show it on demand? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of my question here in the link.
[Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2497237)